# how to access class and its functions from another class

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, programming-languages

This is my first major application using multiple classes. It is written in vb and I know about creating objects of the class and using that instance to call functions of the class. But how do I create an object with constructors to allow another program written in C# to access my classes and functions and accept things from the program.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile your VB classes into a class library (DLL) not an application.

From you C# application you need to add a reference to your newly compiled DLL.  This DLL contains the classes and methods that you can instantiate and call from C#.

Once you've added a reference to the VB DLL from your C# assembly, you can access the VB classes (mostly) as though they were all in the same assembly.  (I say mostly because access modifiers can change this, especially the 'internal' access modifier).

Comment: so theres no need for creating objects with constructors etc. right. Just giving my partner the path to the dll should allow him access to my functions and dont they have to be public shared or something?

Comment: Every class has a constructor. If you don't specify one it has a default parameterless constructor created for you.  Your classes & methods need to be accessible, which means they can't be private.  You need to give him the path of the DLL and he needs to grab it and add a reference to it.  He will then be able to 'see' all the classes in your DLL that are accessible.

Comment: thank you for your response. One more if you dont mind...my overall program function is to produce a list of parsed items to a stream which he said he can provide so as to access. So like you said as long as methods are public or shared it should work?

Comment: Yes - if you have a class called "StreamGenerator" with a method "Generate", both public, he can access the stream by adding a reference to your DLL and then doing:

StreamGenerator generator = new StreamGenerator();
generator.Generate();

Answer (score 3):

Simply create a .NET class library and include that library as a reference inside the C# program.  In .NET all libraries are .DLL files.

Once you do that the library will be available to C# with C# syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim myClassInstance As New MyClass()
```

edit: Ah, you want to define a class with constructors?
If that is the case, try this:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Public Sub New(myNumber As Integer) 'Defines a constructor with an Integer as argument
    End Sub
End Class
```